# View contents of QStandardItemModel in Locals View in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

Is there a way to view the data stored in a `QStandardItemModel` object by using the Locals and Expressions window in Qt Creator, in order to monitor their values while debugging?

I can see the contents of arrays in the Locals window, but for a `QStandardItemModel` the representation does not show me the data inside:
[Image of Qt Creator Locals Window showing a QStandardItemModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci4rX.png).

I am using Qt Creator version 4.0.3 and Qt version 5.7.0.

I have already tried the following, but they did not help:

- Right-clicking the object in the Locals window, choosing 'Change Value Display Format' and setting it to Raw Data, String or Array of 10 Items;
- Checking that 'Load System GDB Pretty Printers' is off under Tools / Options.

I have also tried adding `myQStandardItemModel->item(0,0)->text()` to the Expressions window, but this gives a value of `<no such value>`. However, this expression does work if I place it directly in the code, assigning it to a temporary variable. Although I can debug using this technique, it forces me to add temporary variables to my code and re-compile each time that I discover a need to check a `QStandardItemModel` - is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found that if I switch from using Qt Creator to using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 to debug my code, I am able to see the contents of a `QStandardItemModel` in the Locals window during break mode. The data of the first item in the `QStandardItemModel` can be found at:

```
myQStandardItemModel / QAbstractItemModel / QObject / d_ptr / [Raw View] / d / 
[QStandardItemModelPrivate] / root / [Raw View] / d / d_ptr / [Raw View] / d / children / 
[0] / d_ptr / [Raw View] / d / values / [0] / value
```

The follow screenshot illustrates this:

[image: Image of QStandardItemModel in VS2015 Locals].

I also tried compiling the code in Qt Creator using the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler and debugging using the CDB debugger from the Windows SDK. However, although this did provide more debugging information in the Locals window about a `QStandardItemModel` than MinGW had done, I could not find the actual text data within each item of the `QStandardItemModel`.